# codeigniter .htaccess file unable access css and js file after addition of useragent filter giving 404

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

> codeigniter .htaccess file unable access css and js file after addition of useragent filter giving 404

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
 RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule .? - [S=0]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f   
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d   
 RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error_page.php
```

Comment: Which bits did you add/change exactly? Is this your complete `.htaccess` file? There are a number of errors here, not just those associated with the "user-agent filter". And what is the "user-agent filter" supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # 1
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} AltaVista [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
> RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
>
> # 2
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteRule .? - [S=0]
>
> # 3
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f   
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d   
> RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
> ```

It's unclear which directives you've "added" since #1 and #2 are *nonsense* and aren't actually doing anything. The erroneous `OR` flag on the last `RewriteCond` directive of the first rule results in the rule always being successful and skipping the next rule, which isn't actually doing anything anyway.

So, you could (and probably should) remove #1 and #2 and you will see no change.

The problem with being "unable to access css and js files" is caused by rule #3 (but this isn't associated with a "user-agent filter"). This is checking if the request maps to a file AND a directory, which is impossible so is never processed and the following two rules are not skipped (`S=2`). This means that requests for any static resources (such as CSS and JS files) are passed to the Codeigniter front-controller, rather than "skipping it", which presumably results in a 404 (because they are not valid CI routes).

You need an `OR` flag on the first condition. For example:

```
# 3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d   
RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
```

However, there are still more problems...

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error_page.php
> ```

The first rule that rewrites to the CI front-controller (`index.php`) needs an `L` (or `END`) flag.

And the second rule (that rewrites everything to `/error_page.php`) does not make sense in this context and should be removed.